# obtener el valor de un objeto con un condicional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

estoy con un formulario en MERN, y al editarlo, me gustaría que si el cliente, cambia la foto, esta se actualice con la nueva foto y esta quede en la base de datos.

Si el cliente cambia otros datos del formulario, pero mantiene la misma foto, que ésta se vuelva a cargar.

Al hacer el findbyidandUpdate, creo un nuevo objeto, con todos los parámetros y sus valores.

Como los valores de texto los puedo cargar desde el body, los pongo en un objeto y para la imagen, intento hacer un condicional, para que tome los valores que ya hay cargados en el body o los nuevos desde el req.file (que me trae el nuevo url desde cloudinary).

Antes de hacer el condicional si manualmente usaba

```
let newData = {    
    categoria: req.body.categoria,
    subCategoria: req.body.subCategoria,
    title: req.body.title,
    price: req.body.price,
    description: req.body.description,
    images: {     //me daba el valor del nuevo url
      url: req.file.path,
      filename: req.file.filename,
    },
  };
```

Pero Si usaba:

```
let newData = {    
    categoria: req.body.categoria,
    subCategoria: req.body.subCategoria,
    title: req.body.title,
    price: req.body.price,
    description: req.body.description,
    images: {     //me daba los valores del body, y se volvia a 
 cargar la misma foto
      url: req.body.images,
      filename: req.body.imagesfilename,
    },
  };
```

Ahora quiero usar el condicional:

```
const getCondition = () => {
    if (req.file.path !== undefined){
     // console.log('vamos bien')
     images= {url: req.file.path,
      filename: req.file.filename}    
    }else{  
      images= {
        url: req.body.images,
        filename: req.body.imagesfilename}
    }
  }
  const result = getCondition()

let dataBody = {
    categoria: req.body.categoria,
    subCategoria: req.body.subCategoria,
    title: req.body.title,
    price: req.body.price,
    description: req.body.description,    
  }  

  let newData = {
    ...dataBody,
    ...result
    
  }
```

Pero no hay manera de que funcione. Alguien me puede orientar, por donde me estoy equivocando? muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

**EDICION Y SOLUCION**

Para solucionarlo he encontrado una respuesta que dejo aquí como código y el link de la persona que lo soluciono.

para identificar que el archivo enviado era undefined y entonces agregar al objeto images con los nuevos valores o no....

```
...(typeof(req.file)!=="undefined" && {
      images: {
        url: req.file.path,
        filename: req.file.filename,
      }
    })
```

de tal manera que mi objeto queda de esta manera.

```
let dataBody = {
    categoria: req.body.categoria,
    subCategoria: req.body.subCategoria,
    title: req.body.title,
    price: req.body.price,
    description: req.body.description,
    ...(typeof(req.file)!=="undefined" && {
      images: {
        url: req.file.path,
        filename: req.file.filename,
      }
    }),
  };
```

mucho más simple. no caía que el undefined venía dado porque el objeto en si era undefined, no el valor de la variable.

el link de la persona que lo solucionó es este.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52191440/request-body-file-empty-or-not-in-node-js